# How do I organise divs that are nested inside each other?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve, but I'm having trouble with `Main Body` and `Side Box`. The issue I'm having is the `Main Body` is completely under the `Side Box`, instead of being how it should be in the image above(kind of wrapping around `Side Box`).

Is someone able to lead me in the right direction in terms of using CSS layout techniques?

So far this is what I've done

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebox">
        <h2>Side box</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>Body</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.main {
   width: 40%;
}

div.header {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}

div.sidebox {
   float: right;
   width: 30%;
   height: 50%;
}

div.body {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try floating the side box element to the right.

The key here is that the `.sidebox` element appears before the `.main` element in the source code.

```css
.title {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sidebox {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: gray;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">The title goes here</h1>
<div class="sidebox">The side box text. Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis, diam orci tincidunt magna, ut interdum magna arcu vel elit. </div>
<div class="main">  
<p>Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis, diam orci tincidunt magna, ut interdum magna arcu vel elit. Nunc molestie lacus non urna eleifend mattis. Praesent ipsum nulla, tempor malesuada lacinia quis, elementum et tellus.</p>
<p>Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis, diam orci tincidunt magna, ut interdum magna arcu vel elit. Nunc molestie lacus non urna eleifend mattis. Praesent ipsum nulla, tempor malesuada lacinia quis, elementum et tellus.</p>  
<p>Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis, diam orci tincidunt magna, ut interdum magna arcu vel elit. Nunc molestie lacus non urna eleifend mattis. Praesent ipsum nulla, tempor malesuada lacinia quis, elementum et tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `#sidebox` inside `#main` then apply `float: right`

```css
div { padding: 1em; }

#header { border:2px solid red; }

#main { border: 2px solid lightblue; overflow: auto; }

#side { float: right; border:2px solid orange; }
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="side">Side Box</div>
  Main body
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8kjjh2u6/

Comment: Better to go with class instead id